# Wird in irgendeinem deutschsprachigen Land "Atelier" bevorzugt als Maskulinum verwendet?

Tags: gender

Meine Schülerin kam heute mit einem Deutschbuch für Chinesen zu mir. Darin wird das Wort *Fotoatelier* (dort mit *f* geschrieben) als Maskulinum gelehrt. Der Duden nennt für *Atelier* nur das Neutrum.

Comment: Habe ich noch nie als Maskulinum gesehen (aber auch noch nie in ein chinesisch-deutsches Wörterbuch geschaut)

Comment: Am Rande: [*Foto* mit *f* war schon vor der Rechtschreibreform wirklich nichts Neues.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Foto%2CPhoto&year_start=1900&year_end=2016&corpus=20) (Oder meinst Du, dass es wirklich klein geschrieben wird?)

Comment: Beim OCR der Vorlage ausversehen ein "n" als ein "m" gelesen? :-)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich wollte nur ausdrücken, dass ich die Orthographie übernommen habe.

Comment: Natürlich stimme ich auch zu, dass _Atelier_ ein Neutrum ist. Wenn ich aber mal komplett vergesse, was ein Atelier ist und nur nach dem Klang des Wortes gehe, könnte es auch eine männliche Person sein, die sich um ein "Atel" kümmert (was immer das sein mag). Ähnlich wie ein Sommelier, Conférencier oder Croupier. Zugegeben, das taugt nicht als Antwort, aber ich fand den Gedanken interessant.

Answer (score 5):

So viele deutschsprachige Länder gibt es ja nicht... Maskulin ist naheliegend, weil das Wort ursprünglich (im Französischen) ein Maskulinum ist. In Österreich und der Schweiz ist es trotzdem ein Neutrum, genauso wie in Deutschland. Auch das ist naheliegend, weil im Französischen das Neutrum im Maskulinum aufgegangen ist. (Mir scheint, dass das Vorläuferwort ein Neutrum gewesen sein dürfte, aber für diese Aussage bin ich nicht qualifiziert.) Ich kenne auch eher das umgekehrte Phänomen: Das Wort *Service* ist in Österreich (zumindest Wien) in jeder Bedeutung ein Neutrum, in Deutschland dagegen nur dann, wenn es sich um ein Porzellan-Set handelt.

Allerdings scheint es im Lëtzebuergeschen, das ja einen besonders starken französischen Einfluss hat, tatsächlich "männlech" (nicht "sächlech") zu sein. Quelle: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Atelier und http://www.lod.lu/ . Das dürfte allerdings kaum der Grund für diesen Fehler gewesen sein.

Comment: Fr. atelier geht auf Lat. astula f. zurueck.

Comment: @fdb: Ich dachte, afrz. *astelier* ginge auf ein davon bzw. afrz. *astele*) abgeleitetes Adjektiv zurück. Dann wird das Genus natürlich durch das Genus des ursprünglich mitzudenkenden Substantivs bestimmt, nicht durch das Genus des Grundworts.